# How do I get a mirrored queue using stack?

Tags: python, queue, stack

I have defined the `Stack` and `Queue` class already so I can use any of the Queue methods - `Queue()`, `enqueue()`, `dequeue()`, `peek()`, `size()` and `is_empty()` and any of the Stack ADT methods: `Stack()`, `push()`, `pop()`, `peek()`, `size()` and `is_empty()`.

What I basically need to do is modify the parameter `Queue` object so that the original queue items appear in their original order followed by a copy of the queue items in reverse order.

Here is what I have so far. But this is only giving me the reversed queue. Can someone help how I can modify the queue to both the original and reversed versions.

The `Stack` class:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        if Stack.is_empty(self) == True:
            return None
        else:
            return self.items.pop()
    def peek(self):
        if Stack.is_empty(self) == True:
            return None
        else:
            return self.items[-1]
    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)
```

`Queue` class:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0,item)

    def dequeue(self):
        if len(self.items)==0:
            raise IndexError("ERROR: The queue is empty!")
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def peek(self):
        if Queue.is_empty(self) == True:
            raise IndexError("ERROR: The queue is empty!")
        else:
            return self.items[-1]
            
    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.other = other
        if self.items == self.other:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def clear(self):
        del self.items[:]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.items[::-1])
```

Function I am required to define:

```
def mirror_queue(q):
    stack = Stack()

    while not q.is_empty():
        stack.push(q.dequeue())

    while not stack.is_empty():
        q.enqueue(stack.pop())
```

---test

```
q1 = Queue()
q1.enqueue(1)
q1.enqueue(2)
q1.enqueue(3)
print(q1)
mirror_queue(q1)
print(q1)
```

---Expected Output

```
Queue: [1, 2, 3]
Queue: [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
```

---Gotten Ouput

```
Queue: [1, 2, 3]
Queue: [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

`mirror_queue` seems to just reverse your queue.

My approach:
Don’t change the original `q` but reverse a copy of `q1` called `q1r`.
Afterwards concat those two which then is your result (`q1 + q1r`).

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Queue' and 'Queue'` This is the error I am getting.

Comment: Yeah that is not very surprising. You might want to define a function (or better a method in Queue) which concats two queues.
So you end up with `d1.concat(d2) -> d3`. I don’t know how your Qs are defined.

Comment: I can't update the Queue class because it has been predefined already. I have edited my question to display the `Stack` and `Queue` classes.

Comment: So make an external function which does the concat.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function dequeue, it takes out one item from your queue, so when the first loop ends you have an empty queue and the stack with 3 elements. When you pop from your stack it enqueue back to your queue in reverse order.
You should make a copy of the elements of the queue without dequeue it in order to archive what you want.